# Why onMenuItemSelected didnt respond ??? with ActionBar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Hy im trying to make a Intent / Toast by onMenuItemSelected with ActionBarSherlock in my Activity. But i already insert the code like example in web but it didnt respond. please tell me where the wrong code ???

This is my Code

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
    SubMenu sub = menu.addSubMenu("more");
    MenuItem ShareButton = sub.getItem();
    ShareButton.setIcon(R.drawable.more);
    ShareButton.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS| MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_home, sub);

    return true;

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.menu_item_account:
            Toast.makeText(myContext, "You Choosed Account",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return true;
        case R.id.menu_item_setting:
            Toast.makeText(myContext, "You Choosed Setting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return true;
        case R.id.menu_item_exit:
            Toast.makeText(myContext, "You Choosed Exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**THE SOLUTION**

This is my new Code. Just Remove the OnOptionMenuSelected method, and just Use onMenuItemSelected :

@Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {

```
    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    switch (itemId) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        finish();
        break;
    case R.id.menu_item_account:
        Toast.makeText(myContext, "Anda memilih Account",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.account_contoh_layout);
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_item_setting:
        Toast.makeText(myContext, "Anda memilih Setting",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_contoh_layout);
        return true;

    }

    return true;
}
```

@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

```
    // Used to put dark icons on light action bar
    SubMenu sub = menu.addSubMenu("");

    MenuItem ShareButton = sub.getItem();
    ShareButton.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_more);
    ShareButton.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS
            | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_home, sub);

    return true;

}
```

Comment: just syso the item.getItemId inside onOptionsItemSelected and see what menu item get selected...

Comment: do we need to add return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); inside onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) other than return true;

Comment: i just discovered the solution... :D.  its wierd cuz, "onOptionItemSelected" didnt work...  instead, "onCreateOptionMenu" method work with "onMenuItemSelected".....  dunno why...  :(

Comment: its glad to hear you solved it, pls post that solution and mark as correct answer

Comment: just adding the solution.. sorry if so messy :)

Comment: please post it as an answer